# Get Name Current Function

Tags: function, macros, d

Is there a way to get the name of the current function in D? I'm looking for something similar to `__FUNCTION__` in C++.

I would like to use this name to pass it into an Exception. The Exception would get thrown if a function is not supported (yet) for the current platform the user is on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`__FUNCTION__`](http://dlang.org/traits.html#Special%20Keywords) should work, even as a default argument to another function or exception constructor so it is filled in automatically.

Comment: `__FUNCTION__` is non standard, see this answer for more information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c

Comment: @DwayneTowell That's C++.