# Get all the functions' names from c/cpp files

Tags: c, clang

For example, there is a `C` file `a.c`, there are three functions in this file: `funA()`, `funB()` and `funC()`.

I want to get all the function names from this file.

Additionally, I also want to get the start line number and end line number of each function.

Is there any solution?

Can I use clang to implement it?

Comment: Do you want to do this from your program at runtime, or do you want a script or something to parse the source?

Comment: Take a look at the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c

Comment: It's a static analysis, not at runtime. I tried to use python to implement it, however it is so complex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution that works well for the job is [**cproto**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cproto/). It will scan source files (in K&R or ANSI-C format) and output the function prototypes. You can process entire directories of source files with a `find` command similar to:

```
find "$dirname" -type f -name "*.c" \
-exec /path/to/cproto -s \
-I/path/to/extra/includes '{}' >> "$outputfile" \;
```

While the `cproto` project is no longer actively developed, the `cproto` application continues to work very, very well. It provides function output in a reasonable form that can be fairly easily parsed/formatted as you desire.

**Note:** this is just one option based on my use. There are many others available.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. It is so helpful to me.

Answer (score 5):

You can compile the file and use nm http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nm_(Unix) on the generated binary.  You can then just parse the output of nm to get the function names.

If you want to get line numbers, you can use the function names to parse the source file for line numbers.

All the this can be accomplished with a short perl script that makes system calls to gcc and nm.

This is assuming you are using a *nix system of course...

Comment: Yes, the system is linux(centOS), and it works. Thanks.

Comment: `nm` is a great hint. You probably want to get only functions defined in the file, and not others - in that case filter only "T" symbols, defined in the text section:  `nm foo.cpp.o | grep " T "`. For C++, you'd also need to run `c++filt` on each function to get its demangled name.

Answer (score 2):

you can use ctags which is pretty simple and straight forward. you can run ctags like

```
ctags -x --c-kinds=f
```

this will output the tags(function names)