# __func__ not replaced in preprocessed output

Tags: c++, c, macros

I was reading about `__FUNCTION__` / `__func__` in C/C++ (they are used to print the name of the function in which they are used). Every place I read they said that these are macros and are replaced at preprocessing time. So, I investigated this by seeing the preprocessed output using command `gcc -E prog.c`. But I saw that neither `__func__` nor `__FUNCTION__` were replaced by the preprocessor by the function name.

So, is it a macro? If not, what is it and how is it implemented?

**EDIT**

Even tried `cpp prog.c`. But still not replaced.

Also [__FILE__, __LINE__, and __FUNCTION__ usage in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/597078/2407962) this post says that it never affects performance. Please clarify.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They are implemented as (and are) "magic variables". [The manual says](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.2/gcc/Function-Names.html#Function-Names):

> GCC provides three magic variables that hold the name of the current function, as a string. 
>   The first of these is `__func__`, which is part of the C99 standard:
>
> The identifier `__func__` is implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately
>   following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> ```
> static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
> ```
>
> appeared, where `function-name` is the name of the lexically-enclosing function. This name 
>   is the unadorned name of the function.

They typically cannot be implemented as preprocessor macros; the preprocessor doesn't parse function scopes. Of course a preprocessor *could* be made to understand enough of the syntax to know where functions begin and end, but typically they're not operating at that level.

Answer (score 6):

`__func__` is essentially a pre-defined variable, not a macro. Where `__FUNCTION__` will be expanded, `__func__` will not, and will be used as if you defined the following in your function:

```
static const char __func__[] = "function-name";
```

or

```
static const char __func__[] = __FUNCTION__;
```

Please refer to:

> The intent of `__func__` is similar to `__FUNCTION__`, but the delivery is different.

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG21/docs/papers/2004/n1642.html