# How do predefined macro's __FILE__, __LINE__, __func__ ,stringify(#) work?

Tags: c++, macros

If my compiler supports these predefined macros (`__FILE__, __LINE__, __func__`) then I can safely use them and assume it will always report the right file and line according to : [__FILE__, __LINE__, and __FUNCTION__ usage in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c)

I also read that variable names, line numbers and such aren't relevant to the assembly end-code that is executed (the actual .exe file produced from .cpp code), if this is the case then how do these macros work when used in code? How is a `__LINE__` macro represented in assembly code? How can the .exe file know the correct line number of the original .cpp source when it comes across a `__LINE__` macro?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> How is a **LINE** macro represented in assembly code?

It's not. These are *preprocessor* macros. Once the preprocessor runs, they are replaced with literals.

For example, if you had this code:

```
void foo() {
    printf("%d", __LINE__);
}
```

The preprocessor will turn it into this:

```
void foo() {
    printf("%d", 2);
}
```

Comment: So the preprocessor checks every usage of these macro and replaces them with numbers?

Comment: @JameyD The preprocessor does *expansion* on all macros.

Answer (score 2):

1) "macros" like `__FILE__` and `__LINE__` are expanded by the compilation system's ["preprocessor".](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor).  The source text is modified before the compiler itself actually sees it.

2) This is true of build-in macros like "`__LINE__`".  It's equally true for any macro you create, with the [#define](http://www.cs.cf.ac.uk/Dave/C/node14.html) statement.

3) Things like "line numbers" and "function names" are important to debuggers.  Debug information is generated by the compiler itself (not the preprocessor).  It's related to - but different from - either macro expansion or assembly code generation.

Debug information is usually saved directly in your executable file (along with assembler instructions, string literals, etc) as "metadata".

You can read more here: ["How Debuggers Work"](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/02/07/how-debuggers-work-part-3-debugging-information)

ADDENDUM:

Like debugger metadata (above), **func** is similar - but different.

From the C99 standard:

**6.4.2.2 Predefined identifiers**

Semantics:

1. The identifier __func_ _ shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if, immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration

   `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`

appeared, where function-name is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

2. This name is encoded as if the implicit declaration had been written in the source character set and then translated into the execution character set as indicated in translation phase 5.
3. EXAMPLE 
   Consider the code fragment

   `#include <stdio.h>
    void myfunc(void) {
      printf("%s\n", __func__);
      /* ... */
   }`

Each time the function is called, it will print to the standard output stream:

`myfunc`

You'll also see `__FUNCTION__` in many C compilers, but it was never standard.

You can read more here:

[__FILE__, __LINE__, and __FUNCTION__ usage in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c)