# Indicating function and line number after giving error or exception

Tags: c++, error-handling

Suppose that I tried to open a file but the file does not exist. I could check this with `is_open()` or `catch` an exception. But I would like to know in which function this action was attempted and on which line. If it is tricky to get line number, I am still OK with the function name. How can I do this?

Comment: This answer will fit your exact needs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c

Answer (score 1):

C99 introduces __func__, and GCC has provided __FUNCTION__ for a long time. Both of these are strings containing the name of the current function.

source: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html