# Unknown symbol in c++ string throws errors

Tags: string, c++11, syntax

There is a snippet of code I took from an example and it uses a symbol unknown to me, namely `»`, and I can not find anything about it! The snippet is split onto two lines, but if I remove the split in the string, it doesn't throw an error, assumingly because `»` then becomes part of the "..." string.

```
cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' »
   AS _message'..." << endl;
```

However, another usage of the symbol not involved directly in a string throws an error as well:

```
cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " »
   << __LINE__ << endl;
```

Is this bad syntax for just continuation of a string?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Read about [function name](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html) in GCC documentation. See also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/597081/841108) to a near duplicate question.

Comment: Also `»` is not a valid character in C++11 code (outside of literal strings, literal chars, and comments). Did you enable all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) in your compiler? What are the *exact* diagnostics??

Comment: Thank you, I think that answers my question. BTW, The whole code example can be found here on Oracle's website: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-cpp/en/connector-cpp-examples-complete-example-1.html

Comment: You probably should signal a bug (very probably a documentation bug) to Oracle.

Comment: And yes, I do have all warnings and Wextra enabled for GCC. I am using codeblocks.

Comment: The only error thrown is for not terminating a string: connect.cpp|43|error: missing terminating " character|

Comment: » is alt code (alt+175). But the error is not due to this . If you press 'enter' in between then this will become non terminating string.

Comment: This is a [guillemet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillemet), and has no business floating around in C++ code. This is definitely an issue with the website.

Comment: Thanks for that information @Quentin, I am glad someone was able to find out what it was!