# How to get Line Numbers on execution of C++

Tags: c++

Is there an option to provide line numbers on output from the C++ Execution to trace the errors? Sid Kraft

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_FILE\_\_, \_\_LINE\_\_, and \_\_FUNCTION\_\_ usage in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597078/file-line-and-function-usage-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean. Do you want to log errors?

Comment: You may want to learn how to use a debugger first rather than dumping log info to sort through after the fact.

Comment: Do you want to prefix all output to console with line numbers?

Comment: Not sure what the comment means, _FILE_LINE_, and FUNCTION. I am talking about the options to add line numbers for the compiled file out put when the complier issues errors. The lines in my source file after compilation do not have line numbers and therefore when the compiler says error n, implied at a particular line, I cannot tell which line unless I physically count down each line until I get the the "guesses" statement. As and Example, may be in the "pull down" tab Project Options C++ or? Hopefully this will shed more light on the problem.